# ReactJS: How to get property in a component container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm using a component in my JSX file and I'm passing a property value to this component like this:

**anything.jsx**

```
import Example from '/containers/example.js'

class Anything extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Example type='article' />
        )
    }
}
```

Below you see, that the component is filled with data via container. Now I need to get the property value in that container to pass it as a value for subscription.

The component has `type` value `article`. At the end I need to get this value in the subscription like `Meteor.subscription('exampleDetail', mainID, 'article')`. How do I pass that value?

**Example component (components/example.jsx)**

```
export default class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const   { type } = this.props

        console.log(type);
    }
}
```

**Example container (containers/example.js)**

```
import Example from '../components/example.jsx'

export default createContainer(() => {
    const   mainID       = Session.get('mainID'),
            // ??? How to get type value? 
            subscription = Meteor.subscribe('exampleDetail', mainID, type)

    loading  = !subscription.ready()
    results  = Collection.find().fetch()

    return { results, loading }
}, Example)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change to `createContainer((props) => { console.log(props)  ...}`